# Post JSON to Asp.net through AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

I currently am working on a website just for fun using AngularJS and ASP.net, this post is a more generalized question because I'm not wondering exactly how to do this, I'm more or less wondering what the best practices are.  Currently I have a method in Angular like this

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.form));
    $http.post("/post/new", "'" + JSON.stringify($scope.form) + "'").
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Success")
            $location.path("/news");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
};
```

And then my corresponding Asp.net code:

```
    [HttpPost][Route("New")]
    public IHttpActionResult New([FromBody] string input)
    {
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(input);
        Post p = new Post { Title = (string)json["title"], content = (string)json["content"] };
        db.Posts.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```

However I don't believe this is best practice, because first I'm sending everything in as a string and parsing it, but also because if my Title or Content items have an ' character then the program errors out.  I'm wondering what is the best way to do this.  I believe another way to do it is to pass in my model as parameters to my method, but I'm wondering if there are also other ways to do this besides that as well.  Like I said, this isn't an extremely specific question, I just want to know best practices.  (A little bit of code to back up your response would be much appreciated)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow JSON.Net to do the deserialization for you in the pipleline rather than in your method.  In addition, just post the object itself rather than building out a json string

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $http.post("/post/new", $scope.form).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Success")
            $location.path("/news");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
};

[HttpPost][Route("New")]
public IHttpActionResult New([FromBody] Post input)
{
    db.Posts.Add(input);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```